# Define new object inside class python

Tags: python, class, member-functions

I am learning about classes and member functions, and I would like to know what is the correct way to implement this:

```
class window:

  def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.width=width
    self.height=height

  def shift(self,shift_x,shift_y):
    self.x=self.x+shift_x
    self.y=self.y+shift_y

  def divide(self):
    window A
    A.x=(self.x)/2
    A.y=(self.y)/2
    A.width=(self.width)/2
    A.height=(self.height)/2
    return A
```

How do I implement the divide function correctly? where I want it to return the same class? I know I am predefining A like in C++, but I'm not sure if this is necessary or what is the correct workaround, since I'm getting an error for doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is:

```
def divide(self):
    newWindow = window(self.x/2, self.y/2, self.width/2, self.height/2)
    return newWindow
```

To create an instance of a class, you call it, like `window(...)`, passing whatever arguments it needs.

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to familiarze yourself with the basics of Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = window(self.x/2, self.y/2, self.width/2, self.height/2)
```

Exactly the same way you'd create an object outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating a class is done with `my_instance = MyClass()`. You should probably take a look at the official Python tutorial's section on classes and objects: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html